# Pivot longer data when time indicator is in middle of column name in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pivot, tidyverse

I am having an issue with poviting my data to longer because the "time" indicator is in the middle of the columns' names.
So this is what the data looks like:

```
data
  id wei4_mz kpx_2350flag kpx_3730 var1_190f var2_190f var3_190f var1_430va var2_430va var3_430va
1  1       2            2        1         1         0         1          a          b          c
2  2       3            2        1         1        NA         1          b          b          b
3  3       4            4        2         1         1         0          a          b          a
4  4       1            2       NA         1         1         1          b          z          b
5  5       2            1        0         1         1         1          z          z          b
```

What I want is to pivot all columns that start with "var" and to split them based on the value they take after "var" and before "_", basically the numbers 1:3. I also wanted to add these numbers to a new column names `wave`. So that I can have something like this:

```
    id wave kpx_2350flag kpx_3730 var_190f var_430va
1   1    1            2        1        1         a
2   1    2            2        1        0         b
3   1    3            2        1        1         c
4   2    1            2        1        1         b
5   2    2            2        1        1         b
6   2    3            2        1       NA         b
7   3    1            4        2        1         a
8   3    2            4        2        1         b
9   3    3            4        2        0         a
10  4    1            2       NA        1         b
11  4    2            2       NA        1         z
12  4    3            2       NA        1         b
13  5    1            1        0        1         z
14  5    2            1        0        1         z
15  5    3            1        0        1         b
```

Here's code to create both dfs:

```
    data <- data.frame(id = c(1:5),
                   wei4_mz = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2),
                   kpx_2350flag = c(2, 2, 4, 2, 1),
                   kpx_3730 = c(1, 1, 2, NA, 0),
                   var1_190f = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
                   var2_190f = c(0, NA, 1, 1, 1),
                   var3_190f = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                   var1_430va = c("a", "b", "a", "b", "z"),
                   var2_430va = c("b", "b", "b", "z", "z"),
                   var3_430va = c("c", "b", "a", "b", "b"))
ideal <- data.frame( id = c(1, 1, 1,
                             2, 2, 2, 
                             3, 3, 3,
                             4, 4,4, 
                             5, 5, 5),
                     wave = c(1, 2, 3,
                              1, 2, 3,
                              1, 2, 3,
                              1, 2, 3,
                              1, 2, 3),
                     kpx_2350flag = c(2, 2,2,
                                      2, 2,2,
                                      4, 4,4,
                                      2, 2,2,
                                      1, 1,1
                                      ),
                     kpx_3730 = c( 1, 1,1, 
                                  1,1, 1,
                                  2,2,2,
                                  NA, NA, NA,
                                  0, 0, 0),
                     var_190f = c( 1, 0, 1,
                                   1, 1, NA,
                                   1, 1, 0,
                                   1, 1, 1,
                                   1, 1, 1),
                     var_430va = c("a", "b", "c",
                                   "b", "b", "b",
                                   "a", "b", "a",
                                   "b", "z", "b",
                                   "z", "z", "b"))
```

Any idea on how to solve this? It's been really giving lots to do.

THank you!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `pivot_longer` after rearranging the column name substring for 'vars..' columns with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_replace(., "(\\d+)(_.*)", "\\2:\\1"), 
       starts_with('var')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('var'), names_to = c(".value", "wave"), 
        names_pattern = "(.*):(\\d+)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 7
      id wei4_mz kpx_2350flag kpx_3730 wave  var_190f var_430va
   <int>   <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>    
 1     1       2            2        1 1            1 a        
 2     1       2            2        1 2            0 b        
 3     1       2            2        1 3            1 c        
 4     2       3            2        1 1            1 b        
 5     2       3            2        1 2           NA b        
 6     2       3            2        1 3            1 b        
 7     3       4            4        2 1            1 a        
 8     3       4            4        2 2            1 b        
 9     3       4            4        2 3            0 a        
10     4       1            2       NA 1            1 b        
11     4       1            2       NA 2            1 z        
12     4       1            2       NA 3            1 b        
13     5       2            1        0 1            1 z        
14     5       2            1        0 2            1 z        
15     5       2            1        0 3            1 b
```

Comment: Great. Thanks so much! One thing I forgot to mention in the Q is that I wanted to add the number that identifies the time to a column called "wave" in the output. I edited sorry. But how would you do that?